# Matrix-vector multiplication expressed as inner products with elements of an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Let $A$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix and $x$ a row vector of size $n$.
I've encountered the following identity in some lecture notes and am having a hard time understanding it:

$$xA = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\langle x,u_{i}\right\rangle Au_{i}$$

Here $u_1, \ldots , u_n$ are elements of an orthonormal basis of the space.
Why is this true?

(This is one part of a proof, and the motivation being that $A$ is diagonizable w.r.t. the $u_i$ which factors in to the subsequent analysis)

Comment: Is A symmetric?

Comment: @elexhobby Oops, forgot to mention that - Yes, $A$ is symmetric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true, the correct identity is the following:
$$Ax = \sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,u_i\rangle Au_i$$
where $x$ is an $n\times 1$ column vector.

**Proof 1**

Let $A = (\vec a_1\ \   \vec a_2\ \  \vec a_3\ \  …\ \ \vec a_n)$ and $x = \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\.\\.\\.\\x_n}$, then $$LHS = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\vec a_i = RHS$$

**Proof 2**

We know that identity matrix $I = \sum_{i=1}^nu_iu_i^T$. Hence, 
$$LHS=Ax$$
$$ = A\sum_{i=1}^nu_iu_i^T x$$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^n(Au_i)(u_i^Tx)$$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,u_i\rangle Au_i$$

Hence proved

Comment: After you posted this answer, the OP added that $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Even then, the given equation is incorrect. LHS is $1\times n$ whereas RHS is $n\times 1$.

Comment: Assuming that the first sentence of the question correctly describes the givens, wouldn’t the correct equation then be $xA=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,u_i\rangle\,u_iA$?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct, and it is just the transpose of what I proved to be correct.